# Cancelling an async context manager

Tags: python, python-asyncio

It's easy enough to get a handle to a task for cancellation:

```py
task = loop.create_task(coro_fn())

# later
task.cancel()
```

Is it possible to do the same for async context managers?

```py
async with foo() as bar:
   # is it possible to cancel before getting here,
   # while waiting to enter the context manager?
   await bar.baz()

# later
# How do I get a handle to the context manager for cancellation?
```

Is there any way to do this? Or does the context manager code need to run in its own task?

Comment: what exactly do you want to cancel?

Comment: Execution is suspended in `__aenter__` of the context manager (perhaps waiting to acquire a resource). I want to cancel it, so that `asyncio.CancelledError` gets raised from it.

Comment: You cancel a task suspended in `__aenter__` just like anything else in asyncio - by ensuring it's in a task and calling `cancel()` on that. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I get a handle to the context manager for cancellation?

You don't, at least not directly - a context manager is just a convenient packaging for methods to acquire and release a resource. The `async with foo() as bar: ...` from your question desugars to something roughly like:

```
_cm = foo()
bar = await _cm.__aenter__()
try:
    await bar.baz()
finally:
    await _cm.__aexit__(*sys.exc_info())
```

Both `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` are normal awaitables, whose *execution* can be cancelled, just like the execution of `await bar.baz()` inside the `async with` body.

So if by "canceling a context manager" you mean cancel the operation that the `async with` block is currently stuck in, you can do it the same as for any other cancellation. For example, you could extract the `async with` into a coroutine that runs in its own task and `cancel()` that. Note that you'd need to obtain a task anyway to even reach the "later" section without the async context manager getting closed in the process.

Here is an example:

```
async def run_foo():
    async with foo() as bar:
       # is it possible to cancel before getting here,
       # while waiting to enter the context manager?
       await bar.baz()

task = asyncio.create_task(run_foo())
# "task" is the handle you can await or cancel at your leisure
```

Comment: Thanks -  so it seems like I need to manually use ``__aenter__`` to do what I want.

Comment: @Evan That's legitimate (the async context manager protocol is public and you're allowed to call methods like `__aenter__` yourself), but unusual and potentially error-prone, because you have to remember to call `__aexit__` yourself, and do it correctly. Do you really need to cancel only entering the context manager and nothing else the `async with` does? Even if so, couldn't that be checked using a flag set when the `async with` body starts executing?

Comment: Conceptually, the context manager is waiting for a set of items and yielding the first one available (specifically, checking a connection out of a connection pool). I want to cancel because I want to wait for a different set of items (e.g. I want to add an item to the set being waited for). Without cancelling, the context manager could wait an unbounded amount of time before I get the opportunity to add the new item.

Comment: @Evan I see, and that makes sense. An abstraction that wraps a context manager with the appropriate timeout logic might be useful to avoid mistakes at the place of usage, but I won't include it in the answer because I can't tell what to replace it _with_, that part is specific to your application.